# d3js: Function graph not showing correctly when plotting high frequency function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a graph plotter like [google's plotting system](https://www.google.com/search?q=plot%20y%20%3D%20sin(e%5Ex)&oq=plot&aqs=edge.0.69i59j69i57j69i60l3j0i273l2.937j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

The problem is that it's not showing up correctly, some points are missing and it lags out when I increase `TIME_FACTOR` variable beyond 1000. So I am looking for a way to correctly display it and reduce lagginess in it.

This is a working snippet. Thank you

```js
const range = (start, end) => {
  return Array.from({ length: (end - start + 1)}, (_, i) => start + i)
}

let xLeftBound = -5
let xRightBound = 5

const TIME_FACTOR = 1000

const generateData = (start, end) => {
  return range(start, end).map(elem => {
    const x = elem / TIME_FACTOR

    const container = {
      x: x,
      y: Math.sin(Math.exp(x))
    }

    return container
  })
}

const strokeOpacity = (d) => {
  return d === 0 ? 0.5 : 0.2
}

const data = generateData(xLeftBound * TIME_FACTOR, xRightBound * TIME_FACTOR)

const margins = { top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40 }
const width = 700 - margins.left - margins.right
const height = 700 - margins.top - margins.bottom

const svg = d3.select('#graph')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margins.left + margins.right)
  .attr('height', height + margins.top + margins.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margins.left}, ${margins.top})`)

const x = d3.scaleLinear([xLeftBound, xRightBound], [0, width])
const y = d3.scaleLinear([xLeftBound, xRightBound], [height, 0])

const xAxis = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .attr('class', 'x-axis')

const yAxis = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y-axis')

const lineFunction = d3.line()
  .x(d => x(d.x))
  .y(d => y(d.y))

xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(x))
yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(y))

d3.selectAll('g.x-axis g.tick')
  .append('line')
  .classed('gridline', true)
  .attr('stroke', '#0A0A0A')
  .attr('x1', 0)
  .attr('y1', -height)
  .attr('x2', 0)
  .attr('y2', 0)
  .style('shape-rendering', 'crispEdges')
  .style('stroke-opacity', strokeOpacity)

d3.selectAll('g.y-axis g.tick')
  .append('line')
  .classed('gridline', true)
  .attr('stroke', '#0A0A0A')
  .attr('x1', 0)
  .attr('y1', 0)
  .attr('x2', width)
  .attr('y2', 0)
  .style('shape-rendering', 'crispEdges')
  .style('stroke-opacity', strokeOpacity)

const clip = svg.append('defs').append('svg:clipPath')
  .attr('id', 'clip')
  .append('svg:rect')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0)

const line = svg.append('g')
  .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')

line.append('path')
  .datum(data)
  .classed('data-line', true)
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
  .attr('d', lineFunction)

const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 500])
  .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
  .on('zoom', zoomed)

svg.append('rect')
  .classed('pointer-receiver', true)
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('pointer-events', 'all')
  .call(zoom)

function zoomed(event) {
  d3.selectAll('.gridline').remove()

  const newX = event.transform.rescaleX(x)
  const newY = event.transform.rescaleY(y)

  const newLineFunction = d3.line()
    .x(d => newX(d.x))
    .y(d => newY(d.y))

  xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(newX))
  yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(newY))

  const [start, end] = newX.domain()

  if (start < xLeftBound) {
    const dataExtend = generateData((xLeftBound - 5) * TIME_FACTOR, (xLeftBound * TIME_FACTOR) - 1)
    xLeftBound -= 5

    data.unshift(...dataExtend)

    line.selectAll('.data-line')
      .datum(data)
      .attr('d', newLineFunction)
  } else if (end > xRightBound) {
    const dataExtend = generateData((xRightBound * TIME_FACTOR) + 1, (xRightBound + 5) * TIME_FACTOR)
    xRightBound += 5

    data.push(...dataExtend)

    line.selectAll('.data-line')
      .datum(data)
      .attr('d', newLineFunction)
  } else {
    line.selectAll('.data-line')
      .attr('d', newLineFunction)
  }

  d3.selectAll('g.x-axis g.tick')
    .append('line')
    .classed('gridline', true)
    .attr('stroke', '#0A0A0A')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', -height)
    .attr('x2', 0)
    .attr('y2', 0)
    .style('shape-rendering', 'crispEdges')
    .style('stroke-opacity', strokeOpacity)

  d3.selectAll('g.y-axis g.tick')
    .append('line')
    .classed('gridline', true)
    .attr('stroke', '#0A0A0A')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', width)
    .attr('y2', 0)
    .style('shape-rendering', 'crispEdges')
    .style('stroke-opacity', strokeOpacity)
}
```

```html
<div id="graph"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
```